# A condition using pointer

Tags: c++

I have read the topic about "pointer", but i still have some question.

```
// graph.cpp

struct Edge {
    int from;
    int to;
    unsigned int id;
    Edge(): from(0), to(0), id(0) {};
};

struct Vertex {
    int label;
    vector<Edge> edge;
};

class Graph: public vector<Vertex> {
    int gid;
    unsigned int edge_size;
};
```

if I declare a iterator in another file

```
bool get_forward_root (Graph &g, Vertex &v, vector<Edge*> &result) {
    for(vector<Edge>::iterator it = v.edge.begin(); it != v.edge.end(); it++) {
        if(v.label <= g[it->to].label)
        result.push_back(&(*it));
    }
}
```

In my understanding, `it` can be viewed as pointer, since `v.edge.begin()` is the first `Edge` object in `vector<Edge>`, but what is `&(*it)` ?

Question 2. What is the difference between `g`, `&g`, `*g` ?

In my understanding:

- `&g` is the memory address.
- `*g` is a Graph pointer point to a graph object, so we can use Graph *g = new Graph();
- `g` is a Graph object

the difference between *g and g is how we use, for example the two conditions are the same:

condition 1:

```
Graph *g = new Graph();
g->gid = 0;
```

condition 2:

```
Graph g;
g.gid = 0;
```

Question 3.

what is below meaning?

```
Graph &g
```

and why we use `g[it->to].label` not `&g[it->to].label`
Thank very much:)

Comment: you should pick a proper book. you have a lot of questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Question 1: what is &(*it)

`it` acts like a pointer, but it's not a pointer. If it were a pointer, `&*it` would be the same as `it`. In the general case, `&(*it)` is the address (a real pointer) of the object that the iterator `it` points to. We can assume here that the & operator was not overloaded.

> Question 2: What is the difference between g, &g, *g?

`g` is `g`. `&g` is the address of g. `*g` is the object `g` points to (if g is a pointer). Your 2 conditions (I don't understand why you call them conditions) do pretty much the same thing, yes.

> Question 3: what is `Graph &g?`

It's called a reference. When defined, it should be immediately initialized. Think of a reference as another name of an object. (Better, read a book, see below).

All of your questions will be thoroughly answered in any decent C++ beginner book. I especially recommend Lippman's C++ primer for this purpose. Find other good titles [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Graph g; => g is a Graph object ; Graph g* = new Graph() => g is a pointer point to g* ; I can use &g to get the address of g*           (Is my understanding right?) Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

`it` is not a pointer, it is an iterator. Basically it behaves like a pointer (dereference and arrow operators are overloaded) and also like an array index (`++`, `--`, `+=`, etc. advance the iterator to point to the next element. For vectors you may find that useless, but that's great for other containers).

So, `&(*it)` transforms the iterator into a real pointer: it takes the address of the pointed-to object. It does not make much of a difference on a vector though, because all elements are stored into contiguous memory areas.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: `it` is not a pointer, it is an iterator.  Iterators behave
somewhat like pointers, for certain things only, but they aren't
pointers.  In the expression `&(*it)`, `*` dereferences the iterator, to obtain
a reference to the actual object it designates; the `&` then takes the
address of this object, which results in an actual pointer, with pointer
type (which is what the container `result` requires).

Question 2: `g` is the name of an object; in an expression, it
designates the object, and has the type of the object.  `&g` is the
address of the object; an object in itself (albeit temporary) with a 
pointer type.  `*g` isn't legal.  At least as long as no user defined
operators come into play: the type `Graph` could overload `operator*` or
`operator&` to do more or less anything.  (Given the example, with 
`g[it->to]`, it is clear that `Graph` overloads `[]`; this means that
the usual identity `a[b]` means `*(a+b)` doesn't hold.)  And in your
code, `g` is *not* a pointer to a `Graph`, it is a reference, which acts
like an alias—another name for whatever it was initialized with.

With regards to `Graph* g` and `Graph g`: there is a vital difference in
the lifetime of the objects (or in the case of `Graph* g`, the lifetime
of the pointed to object).

Question 3: The `Graph& g` has no relationship with the operator `&`; it
is a means of telling the compiler that `g` is a reference.  A reference
is fundamentally just another name for the initialing object (or the
only name, if the initializing object doesn't have a name otherwise).
References are mostly (but not exclusively) used as function parameters.

Comment: If i add g[vid] in get_forward_root, this is an object? Why i have to use Vertex &v = g[vid] not Vertex *v = g[vid]? Thanks:)

Comment: `g[vid]` is an expression.  It returns a reference, in other words, and alias for an element in the vector.  It's not a pointer, so you can't assign it to a pointer.  (Most of the time, you'd probably just write `Vertex v = g[vid]`, and define an object.)

Comment: Thanks for your advisement! But this sample code is from the author of gSpan, he use `&v = g[vid]` not `v = g[vid]`, do you know the purpose? Thanks:)

Comment: I want to ask another question: `Graph g;` => `g` is a Graph object ; `Graph g* = new Graph();` => `g` is a pointer point to `g*` ; I can use `&g` to get the address of `g*` (Is my understanding right?) Thanks:)

Comment: @Mr.mr. How is `v` defined?  I can't think of any type that `v` could have where `&v = g[vid]` would compile.  Are you sure you don't mean `Vector &v = g[vid];`: this defines a reference to the element in `g`.

Comment: @Mr.mr. `Graph g* = new Graph();` won't compile.  It's not legal C++.